# Track requests per Minute in Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am currently trying to track requests per minute in a Spark Application to use them in another transformation. However the code below will never result in another value than the originally set value of 0 when using the variable in the transformation

```
var rpm: Long = 0


val requestsPerMinute = stream.countByWindow(Seconds(60), Seconds(5)).foreachRDD(rdd => {    
   rdd.foreach(x => {
     rpm = x       
   })    
})

stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.foreach(x => {
    //do something including parameter rpm
  })

}
```

I assume it has to do something with parellization -  what I also tries was to use an RDD or a Broadcast instead of the plain variable. However that resulted in the code not being executed.

What is the recommended way to achieve this in SparkStreaming?

EDIT:
The incoming objects are timestamped, if that helps with anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spark Streaming, there are two levels of execution:

- The scheduling of operations, executed in the driver and,
- The distributed computation on RDDs, executed in the cluster

There are two operations that provide access to both levels: `transform` and `foreachRDD`. In these operations, we have access to the driver's context and we have a reference to an RDD, that we can use to apply computations on it.

In the specific case of the question, to update a local variable, the operation must be executed in the driver's context:

```
val requestsPerMinute = stream.countByWindow(Seconds(60), Seconds(5))
requestsPerMinute.foreachRDD{ rdd =>
    val computedRPM = rdd.collect()(0) // this gets the data locally
    rpm = computedRPM      
}
```

In the original case:

```
rdd.foreach(x => {
  rpm = x       
})
```

the closure: `f(x): Long => Unit = rpm = x` is serialized and executed on the cluster. The side-effects are applied in the remote context and lost after the operation finishes. At the driver level, the value of the variable never changes.

Also, note that is not a good idea to use side-effecting functions for remote execution.